# mySql code for retrieving the params containing array of Integers from android

Tags: android, mysql

I am not able to retrieve all the array elements sent by the volley post request for mySql......stores only the last value

I have already tried to send the size of the array and looped through it in MySQL

```
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("date", date);
    params.put("class1", className1);
    params.put("sec1", section1);

    Integer[] ar = new Integer[80];

    params.put("count", Integer.toString(checkS.size()));

    for (int i = 0; i < checkS.count(); i++) {
        ar[i] = checkS.get(i);
        params.put("records", ar[i].toString());
    }
    return params;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, if I understand your question, but you put every array element into the same Map entry.

```
params.put("records", ar[i].toString());
```

As a result `params` will have only last array element in the `"records"` entry.

The solution: put array elements into different entries, e.g.

```
params.put("records" + i, ar[i].toString());
```

Or serialize array (JSON or just joining the array elements into one string), and put it in the `"records"`.

P.S. There is no point in `ar` array, you can use `checkS` directly

Comment: and how will i be receiving the array in the mySQl side?? and i tried this solution also......but it didnt work dat tym.....can u help me with the mySql side

Comment: I don't know how your application communicates with MySQL now. Add current server side code to the question, please.

Comment: ?php
$clas1 =trim($_POST['class1']);
$sec1 = trim($_POST['sec1']);
$date1=trim($_POST['date']);
$record[]=($_POST['records[]']);
$counts=trim($_POST['count']);
$size=intval($counts);

for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){
    echo $record[$i];
}
    die();

Comment: I mean adding server code to the question :) Anyway, there are a lot of similar questions. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35959135/436938), you should do something like this in the for loop: `params.put("records["+ i + "]", checkS.get(i).toString());`